# Выход ESP8266 в интернет

Tags: wifi, esp8266

Как подключить `ESP8266` к глобальной сети? Я могу сделать так, что оно получит `IP` адрес и в одной Wi-Fi сети я могу ей управлять(95% примеров в интернете), но если мне нужно будет подключиться к `ESP` с другого конца Земли? Хотелось бы подключить ее к своему сайту или хотя бы сделать ей адрес, с которого можно управлять независимо от местонахождения. Все управление планирую делать `GET` запросами

Answer (score 1):

Управление такой штукой лучше делать через полинг tcp или trap udp.

Суть полинга в том что железяка делает запрос на сервер. Сервер открывает соединение и спит до появления команды. Команду посылает в соединение и устройство получив её или ждет следующей команды или делает реконект. Тут следует учесть таймауты и переподключаться до обрыва связи.

Суть трапа в удп в том что железка посылает переодически пакеты "я тут" на сервер. Пакет проходя через роутер открывает порт и ответ с командой вернется по тому же пути что и ушел.

Проброс портов делать не стоит. Основная причина в том что сетеврй стек на контроллере однопоточный и  зашедший скан бот займет железку. Я так онлайн кассу однажды "потерял".

Answer (score 0):

Интернет-роутер, к которому подключено устройство, управляет подсетью, и сам входит в некоторую подсеть.

Например, в вашей сети устройство имеет адрес 192.168.1.100, и маска подсети выглядит так - 192.168.1.255.

А сам роутер имеет например 93.185.19.103, и маска его подсети выглядит так - 93.185.19.255.

Поэтому внешний адрес вашего устройства будет, например, 93.185.19.104.

Интернет имеет иерархическую структуру. Дело в том, что все сообщения, которые адресованы какому-либо устройству в подсети, получают все устройства в данной подсети, и они просто игнорируют пакеты, адресованные не им.

И если вы зададите статический IP, который не адресуется маской подсети вашего устройства, то пакеты, исходящие от него, получат только устройства, подключенную в вашу локальную сеть, а роутер их проигнорирует, поскольку это пакеты, которые физически передаются по его сети, но логически это пакеты из другой подсети.

Comment: Маска подсети - 255.255.255.0 в обоих случаях (255 - та часть адреса которая одинакова для всех устройств в текущей подсети, 0 - изменяемая часть адреса). 192.168.1.255 - это адрес для широковещательных запросов для данной подсети.

Comment: Устройство из локальной сети не будет видно извне ни под каким адресом. Оно будет доступно извне, если настроить на роутере проброс запросов в локальную сеть. Адрес устройства при обращении извне будет совпадать с адресом роутера.

Comment: Маска значения особого не имеет для пакетного трафика. Она о том куда слать arp